Playwright .NET - Associated tests with test cases not being saved to test executions
I've set up a C# dotnet with Playwright repository on Azure for the purpose of running automated UI tests. It is running on net8.0. I've managed to successfully map the each test with the test plans, as per this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops and furthermore, the test case work items do show the correct Test ID association in their information, and they are set on 'automated' status. However, when I run the Azure Pipeline, using dotnet and VsTest assembler (from the Playwright.dll), even though it successfully runs the tests and saves the results, it fails to save the results in each test case as test execution. My pipeline's YAML is the following:
# .NET Desktop

# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net


pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


- powershell: |
   dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Playwright.CLI
   playwright install
  displayName: 'Install Playwright'

# Install VSTest 17.5.0
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
    versionSelector: 'specificVersion'
    testPlatformVersion: '17.6.2'


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'




- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: VsTest - testAssemblies
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: >-
      **\Playwright\bin\Debug\net8.0\Playwright.dll
    platform: $(BuildPlatform)
    configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
    runTestsInIsolation: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2 
  inputs:
   testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
   testResultsFiles: '**/TestResults.trx'
   testRunTitle: 'Current Run'
   publishRunAttachments: true
  condition: succeededOrFailed()



- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: Publish symbols path
  continueOnError: True
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: true
    SymbolServerType: TeamServices
  condition: succeededOrFailed() 


- task: CopyPublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    CopyRoot: 'TestResults.xml'
    Contents: '*'
    ArtifactName: 'TestResults'
    ArtifactType: 'Container'
  condition: succeededOrFailed() 

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
    TargetPath: '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'

To further explain the issue:

I do not have an Azure Service subscription to set up a web app as artifact and then stage to test result
I want to build and run the repository in the pipeline, and the test results to be saved as test executions in the Test Plans, not just as independent nUnit test results.

Any ideas?
